# Image size is wrong after collapse/expanding

Tags: android, resize-image

I have a box that contains:

- a `Button`: touch to collapse or expand the below image.
- an `CustomImageView`: is set `GONE` when collapse, set `VISIBLE` when expand. The image is resized to fill the width of the screen as following code:

  public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

  ```
  public CustomImageView(Context context) {
      super(context);
  }

  public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

      Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
      if (drawable != null)
      {
          int width =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
          int diw = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
          if (diw > 0) {
              int height = width * drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / diw;
              setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
          }
          else {
              super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
          }
      }
      else {
          super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
      }

  }
  ```

  }

At first running default, the image is expanded (`VISIBLE`).

```
+-------------+
|-----(+)-----|
===============
| ----------- |
| |         | |
| |  (IMG)  | |
| |         | |
| ----------- |
===============
```

After press button `+`, the image is `GONE`,

```
+-------------+
|-----(-)-----|
===============
```

Next, pressing button `-`, the image is set `VISIBLE`,

```
+-------------+
|-----(+)-----|
===============
| ----------- |
| |  (IMG)  | |
===============
```

The issue is here, the image is display only part of it, not a full height.
If I use the default support `ImageView` class, it certainly displays correctly, however, it doesn't resize to full-width of the screen (height is resized with width-ratio).

Can anyone point me out about this issue?
Thanks!